# Multivariate recursion with entire negative line as initial domain

Tags: function-construction, programming, recursion

I am trying to write a recursion program with all the negative value n<=0 as the initial domain, where `f[n]` is 0. The following simplified code is successful to obtain the result.

Successful to get the result. Result shows `3`:-

```
f[n_] := f[n] = (If[n <= 0, 0, f[n - 1] + 1]);
f[2.5]
```

I need to extend f to multivariate, and then it becomes unable to obtain the correct value by recursion:-

Failed to get the result. Result shows `f[π,2.5]`:-

```
f[x, n_] := f[x, n] = (If[n <= 0, 0, f[x, n - 1] + 1]);
f[π,2.5]
```

How can I get the result `3`?

Comment: 1.) I am not sure but you probably mean `f[x_, n_] := f[x, n] = (If[n <= 0, 0, f[x, n - 1] + 1]);` 2.) If you define `f` as a two argument function then you have to call it as such, e.g. like `f[Pi,2.5]`.

Comment: Thx. That's my typo. But the problem is still there for `f[Pi,2.5]`. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @HMC Add underscore after `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo: try

```
f[x_, n_] := f[x, n] = (If[n <= 0, 0, f[x, n - 1] + 1])
```

instead of `f[x, n_]` and you get `3`.